# ValueError: time data ' 7:42.3' does not match format '%M:%S.%f' (match)

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Hej,

My time format of my datetime object is like this %M:%S.%f but python apparently does not identify it as so. I have this problem with multiple columns which I want to use for visualisation

data example:

```
0            7:42.3
1            7:51.9
2            7:48.3
3            7:44.2
4            8:01.7
           ...     
111          8:55.5
112          8:17.9
113          8:41.1
114             NaN
115             NaN
Name: CRS1, Length: 116, dtype: object
```

Tried this without success:

```
t = pd.to_datetime(df["CRS1"], format='%M:%S.%f')
```

In seaborn I can plot the data if time is plotted against rank but not if i switch variables around..iE. Athletes Name and Finish time -> TypeError: Neither the `x` nor `y` variable appears to be numeric.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGEKP.png)

Quite new to python, so would appreciate a good explanation to deal with this format.
/Thanks!

Comment: If the first digit(s) really represents minutes, it should be zero padded. see https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: `df["CRS1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["CRS1"].str.zfill(7), format='%M:%S.%f').dt.time`

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney getting a new error with this approach
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: See [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lhu1.png). You could try `.dropna` on the column, but you can see in the linked image that it doesn't cause an issue. Make sure pandas is updated `conda update --all`

Comment: Tried it multiple times even with reformatting the excel input. But pandas still does not identify the format "%M:%S.%f" for the time data. Can I share the file with you?